# Shell Script to find string in pattern

Tags: shell

Hi I want parse following variable :
mystring ="The user 'jai' created the package: 'DevOps Release'"

to read all values in single quote. for instance
var1= jai
var2=DevOps Release

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script which does automatically what you have described:

```
#!/bin/bash
mystring="The user 'jai' created the package: 'DevOps Release'"
var1=`echo $mystring| sed 's/The user '\''//;s/'\'' created.*//'`
var2=`echo $mystring| sed 's/'\''$//;s/.*the package: '\''//'`
echo "user: $var1"
echo "package: $var2"
```

It is not suitable for more general cases. Please give more specific and accurate desciption of your problem.

Comment: Hmm it seems that you are using nested double quotes without escaping, when you are trying to find the releasename. Do it in a separate line... also, this looks really messy - could you maybe post this script formatted as a code, in your question? Also, clarify your requirements?